# What do you call a weighted summary statisitc?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, terminology, weighted-mean

I want to present a summary statistic of 20+ simultaneous classes where each class has an AUC-statistic that I would like to describe in a single statistic, e.g.:

```
| Class | Test cases | AUC  |
|-------|------------|------|
| A     | 34         | 0.81 |
| A1    | 23         | 0.77 |
| A2    | 2          | 0.98 |
| B     | 11         | 0.94 |
|....                       |
```

Simply doing a mean over the AUC will risk that many of the top-performing small categories get too much influence over the average and therefore I would like to do a weighted mean:

$$\overline{AUC_{weighted}}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{categories}{AUC_i * n_i}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{categories}{n_{i}}}$$

Weighting the outcome measures based on the number of test cases in that group seems a nice way of presenting this type of statistics (the same approach could be used for Youden's J etc). It so nice that someone must have presented this before...

**My question**: Is there a name for this type of *a weighted mean based on the number of test cases* that I can refer to?

Comment: It's a "weighted mean AUC".

Comment: @AdamO - yeah - that is my fallback. My question is more if there is a case for when we have weighting by *test cases* as "weighted mean AUC" could in my mind represent any type of weighting, or? My thoughts are along the line - if there is a Youdens index that is simply $Se + Sp - 1$ then this seems like a similar trivial thing.

Comment: You'll have to describe it. Since you use $n$, we would assume that it's some type of frequency weighting. e.g. if experimental results combined over multiple experiments containing uneven number of samples, the $n$ might be the number of samples in each experiment. Good enough for any first pass. I can empathize with how hard it is to describe statistical methods. The revise/resubmit process can bloat a paper out of proportions because you're dropping text left and right to appease a reviewer who has decided to micromanage the methods.